# Angular JS $watch on service object

Tags: angularjs, service, updates

I've searched high and low, tried many 'solutions' and cannot get angular to watch a service correctly.

Service:

```
self = {}; // or self = this;
self.testVar = null;

$interval(function() {
    self.testVar = Math.random();
}, 1000);

return self;
```

Controller:

```
$scope.testVar = myService.testVar;
$scope.$watch('testVar', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
})
```

This code doesn't work. I'd like to avoid using $broadcast as it seems like angular is supposed to handle service updates magically. Any insights are appreciated.

---

EDIT: Solution in controller:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() { return myService.testVar },
    function(newVal) {
        console.log(newVal);
    }
)
```

If anyone cares to explain this behaviour, it would benefit those experiencing the same problem.

---

Upon further investigation, changing the $interval timer to 100ms still results in the controller printing to the console every 1000ms which suggests $scope.$watch is set at a max rate of 1 second. I suppose it's best to use $broadcast or a observer/callback method instead O_o

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.testVar = myService.testVar;
$scope.$watch('testVar', function(newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log(newVal, oldVal);
})
```

In this code you set $scope.testVar from the service. Then you watch it. Nothing changes it again. In your "solution", it works because you are watching the "live" value from the service. You do not need to use $broadcast or observer or callbacks. This will work as expected when you are watching the service value and updating the scope.

Comment: "This will work as expected when you are watching the service value and updating the scope." It doesn't though. If I watch the service value directly like $scope.watch('myService.value', ...) nothing happens...

Comment: When you pass it a string as the first param, it expects that to be a property of the scope. If you want to use the value from the service, you need to pass a function as the first param and return the value from your service call.